# ExcelDna async with cancell all

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I'm building an addin using ExcelDna and I'm trying to use async functions. I want to put a "Stop all" button in my Ribbon but I can't figure out how to bring my own CancellationToken?

In my IExcelAddIn class I have:

```
    internal static CancellationTokenSource _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public static void CalculationCanceled()
    {
        _cancellation.Cancel();
    }

    public static void CalculationEnded()
    {
        _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Stoping");
        _cancellation.Cancel();
    }
```

But how do I run a task that uses this CancellationTokenSource? I've look at the examples and helper libs created by Govert, but can't find any way to use my own source?

I was looking att adding the https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna.Registration/AsyncRegistration.cs Nuget to my project but this also don't seem to support my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the Task with code like the [AsyncTaskUtil](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna.Registration/Utils/AsyncTaskUtil.cs) in the Registration extensions, then you can use `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` to get a combined token source for the Task you create. You'd use this to combine your own `CancellationTokenSource` with the normal token (which cancels if the cell calling the function is cleared).